How to remove all emojis from a string if they are not equal to any of the ones in the object?
How to remove all emojis from a string if they are not equal to any of the ones in the object?
For example:
let allowedEmojis = {
  '': 50,
  '': 150,
  '': 500
};

function filterEmojis() {
  // what should I type here?
}

let str = "Helloo ";
str = filterEmojis(str);

console.log(str); // Helloo 



Can you share some attempts you've made at solving this? That way we're not making the filterEmojis function for you, but rather helping you debug your own solution.

Another, simpler, solution would be to use the callback functionality of String.replace():


const allowedEmojis = {
  '': 50,
  '': 150,
  '': 500,
};

str="Helloo ";

console.log(str.replace(/\p{Emoji}/ug, a=>allowedEmojis[a]?a:""))




function filterEmojis(text: string): string {
    const emojiPattern = /[\p{Emoji}]/gu;
    const allowedSet = new Set(Object.keys(allowedEmojis));
    let result = '';

    for (const letter of text) {
        if (emojiPattern.test(letter) && !allowedSet.has(letter)) {
            continue;
        }
        result += letter;
    }
    return result;
}

The regex might not pass for all Emojis but this is a simple solution to the problem.
